# Linear iterability for set models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory, filters, large-cardinals

As I found some problems in my writing and proof, I have heavily **edited** my questions.

---

So I am reading this corollary in Steel's notes, found [here](http://www.math.cmu.edu/users/jcumming/Appalachian/steel_cmu_2015_files/Iteration-Ultrapowers.pdf), and I am confusing myself over and over again. I hope someone can clarify the situation for me. First some context:

When I say $\omega$-complete ultrafilter, I mean that the intersection of countable sequences of members of that ultrafilter are nonempty. And we may assume that in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, we have linear iterability for normal ultrafilters. Also whenever $M \models \mathsf{ZFC} + `` \mathcal{E} \mbox{ is a family of normal ultrafilters''}$ and $I = \langle U_\alpha: \alpha \lt \lambda\rangle$ is an iteration of $(M, \mathcal{E})$, then $M^I_\infty$ denotes the direct limit of $I$ and $i_{\alpha\infty}$ denote the direct limit embeddings.

Now this is corollary $2.8$ of the above notes, together with the following exercise:

> Corollary $2.8.$ Let $M \models \mathsf{ZFC} + `` \mathcal{E} \mbox{ is a family of normal ultrafilters''}$, with $M$ transitive, and $\omega_1 \in M$. Then $(M, \mathcal{E})$ is linearly iterable. 
> Proof. Working inside $M$, construct a $``\mbox{universal''}$ linear iteration $I = \langle U_\alpha: \alpha \lt \lambda\rangle$ with $(a)$ $\operatorname{cof}(\lambda) = \omega$, and $(b)$ whenever $W \in i_{0\alpha}(\mathcal{E})$, then $i_{\alpha\beta}(W) = U_\beta$ for cofinally many $\beta$. This implies that every $W \in i_{0\infty}(\mathcal{E})$ is $\omega$-complete. Thus $(M^I_\infty, i_{0\infty}(\mathcal{E}))$ is linearly iterable in $V$. Since $i_{0\infty}:M\rightarrow M^I_\infty$, $(M, \mathcal{E})$ is linearly iterable in $V$. $\Box$ 
> Exercise. Prove that every $W \in i_{0\infty}(\mathcal{E})$ is $\omega$-complete, granted $(a)$ and $(b)$.

---

**Questions**:

Now I have partially worked my way through the corollary and have constructed an $I$ with some difference to what is suggested and I think I do understand what's going on, except for the questions I have below:

Firstly, I can only complete the proof with the crucial assumption that $M^I_\infty$ is actually well-founded in $V$. But I don't see how we can show this. It is well-founded from $M$'s perspective, but $V$ may not agree. So what can we say about this?

Secondly, I have proved the exercise but with one key difference. When building $I$, I made sure that $\operatorname{cof}(\lambda) = \omega_1$, instead of the suggested $\omega$! That's because when looking at our sequences from $^\omega W$ like $\langle A_n: n \in \omega \rangle$, we can bound their representatives given by $(b)$ in the iteration and then find some $\langle B_n: n\in\omega\rangle$ and $\alpha$, such that $i_{\alpha\infty}(B_n)=A_n$ and $B_n \in U_\alpha$ for each $n$. Then by normality we would have $i_{0\alpha}(\kappa) \in i_{\alpha{\alpha+1}}(B_n)$ for each $n$ and then we would have $i_{{\alpha+1}\infty}(i_{0\alpha}(\kappa))\in A_n$ for every $n$; and so $i_{{\alpha+1}\infty}(i_{0\alpha}(\kappa))\in \bigcap_n A_n$.

And as you can see from the above proof, I think $\operatorname{cof}(\lambda) = \omega$ is probably a typo right? Also the thing I have written is the only way I can think of that we can use the hypothesis $\omega_1\in M$.

I would really appreciate any thoughts and help, so I can make some progress. Also, sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with a friend on twitter, we came to the following conclusion for the first question:

As $M \models \mathsf{ZFC}$, then each ultrapower is contained within $M$ by the virtue of $M \models \mathsf{Powerset}$. And in general, models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ trap all iterations in themselves(unless of course when the length of the iteration is $\ge \operatorname{Ord}^M$). And since $I$ is iterated in $M$, $M$ can see $M^I_\infty$ as a subclass! At which point it must be well-founded.

This solves most of my confusion. I would still welcome any confirmation about my second question.

Comment: Is 'a friend' Jason Chen? I started to read the same lecture note, and I am stuck on the same point. I will read your question, answer, and seemingly relevant Twitter thread after a short nap and teaching assistance.

Comment: @HanulJeon, Yes. Because of our discussion on twitter, I thought that they may not want me to mention their name directly. Also these notes have many *many* typos. Wish you good luck! :) I have also written a description of the construction of the iteration. I've put that and other things on my blog, [here](https://shervinsorouri.org/iteration-trees-part-ii/).